# Can a Task have multiple awaiters?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-runtime, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I am toying around with an async service for a Windows 8 project and there are some async calls of this service, which should only be called once at a time.

```
 public async Task CallThisOnlyOnce()
 {
      PropagateSomeEvents();

      await SomeOtherMethod();

      PropagateDifferentEvents();
 }
```

Since you cannot encapsulate an async call in a lock statement, i thought of using the `AsyncLock` pattern, but than i thought i might as well try something like this:

```
 private Task _callThisOnlyOnce;
 public Task CallThisOnlyOnce()
 {
      if(_callThisOnlyOnce != null && _callThisOnlyOnce.IsCompleted)
         _callThisOnlyOnce = null;

      if(_callThisOnlyOnce == null)
         _callThisOnlyOnce = CallThisOnlyOnceAsync();

      return _callThisOnlyOnce;
 }

 private async Task CallThisOnlyOnceAsync()
 {
      PropagateSomeEvents();

      await SomeOtherMethod();

      PropagateDifferentEvents();
 }
```

Therefore you would end up with the call `CallThisOnlyOnceAsync` only executed once simultanously, and multiple awaiters hooked on the same Task.

Is this a "valid" way of doing this or are there some drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A task can have multiple awaiters. However, as Damien pointed out, there's serious race conditions with your proposed code.

If you want the code executed each time your method is called (but not simultaneously), then use `AsyncLock`. If you want the code executed only once, then use `AsyncLazy`.

Your proposed solution attempts to combine multiple calls, executing the code again if it is not already running. This is more tricky, and the solution heavily depends on the exact semantics you need. Here's one option:

```
private AsyncLock mutex = new AsyncLock();
private Task executing;

public async Task CallThisOnlyOnceAsync()
{
  Task action = null;
  using (await mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    if (executing == null)
      executing = DoCallThisOnlyOnceAsync();
    action = executing;
  }

  await action;
}

private async Task DoCallThisOnlyOnceAsync()
{
  PropagateSomeEvents();

  await SomeOtherMethod();

  PropagateDifferentEvents();

  using (await mutex.LockAsync())
  {
    executing = null;
  }
}
```

It's also possible to do this with `Interlocked`, but that code gets ugly.

P.S. I have `AsyncLock`, `AsyncLazy`, and other `async`-ready primitives in my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: I liked both answers, but since you added an implementation proposal, i chose yours. Also, i tried to install your Library using Nuget, but failed in my Windows Store project (unable to resolve Microsoft.Bcl.Async)

Comment: Try checking the "include prerelease" checkbox. My package is prerelease (but NuGet doesn't detect that correctly), and `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is also prerelease (which NuGet does detect correctly).

Answer (score 4):

This code looks very "racy" if multiple threads might be involved.

One example (I'm sure there are more). Assume that `_callThisOnlyOnce` is currently `null`:

```
Thread 1                                                          Thread 2

public Task CallThisOnlyOnce()
{
  if(_callThisOnlyOnce != null && _callThisOnlyOnce.IsCompleted)
     _callThisOnlyOnce = null;

  if(_callThisOnlyOnce == null)
                                                                   public Task CallThisOnlyOnce()
                                                                   {
                                                                     if(_callThisOnlyOnce != null && _callThisOnlyOnce.IsCompleted)
                                                                        _callThisOnlyOnce = null;

                                                                     if(_callThisOnlyOnce == null)
                                                                        _callThisOnlyOnce = CallThisOnlyOnceAsync();

                                                                     return _callThisOnlyOnce;
                                                                   }
     _callThisOnlyOnce = CallThisOnlyOnceAsync();

  return _callThisOnlyOnce;
}
```

You now have 2 calls running simultaneously.

As to multiple awaiters, yes you can do this. I'm sure I've seen example code from MS somewhere showing an optimization where e.g. the result of `Task.FromResult(0)` is stored away in a static member and returned any time the function wants to return zero.

I have, however, been unsuccessful in locating this code sample.