# How to have mutliple threads await a single Task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I've read this: [Is it ok to await the same task from multiple threads - is await thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820388/is-it-ok-to-await-the-same-task-from-multiple-threads-is-await-thread-safe) and I don't feel clear about the answer, so here's a specific use case.

I have a method that performs some async network I/O. Multiple threads can hit this method at once, and I dont wan't them all to invoke a network request, If a request is already in progress I want to block/await the 2nd+ threads, and have them all resume once the single IO operation has completed.

How *should* I write the following pseudcode?
I'm guessing each calling thread really needs to get its own `Task`, so each can get it's own continuation, so instead of returning `currentTask` I should return a new `Task` which is completed by the "inner" `Task` from `DoAsyncNetworkIO`.
Is there a clean way to do this, or do I have to hand roll it?

```
static object mutex = new object();
static Task currentTask;

async Task Fetch()
{
    lock(mutex)
    {
        if(currentTask != null)
            return currentTask;
    }

    currentTask = DoAsyncNetworkIO();
    await currentTask;

    lock(mutex)
    {
        var task = currentTask;
        currentTask = null;
        return task;
    }
}
```

Comment: One situation in which I have wondered the same: I retrieve (possibly) the same image from a network location from a method called through multiple async event handlers. I don't want to get the same image from the network twice, I want one task to await the 'downloading' task.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820388/is-it-ok-to-await-the-same-task-from-multiple-threads-is-await-thread-safe (not a duplicate though, IMO)

Comment: Also see this thread (which may have an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530158/can-a-task-have-multiple-awaiters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure that only one thread actually executes the background thread.

Assume your base task (the one actually doing the IO) is in a method called `baseTask()`, which I shall emulate like so:

```
static async Task baseTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting long method.");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Finished long method.");
}
```

Then you can initialise a `SemaphoreSlim` like so, to act a bit like an `AutoResetEvent` with initial state set to `true`:

```
static readonly SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Then wrap the call to `baseTask()` in a method that checks `signal` to see if this is the first thread to try to run `baseTask()`, like so:

```
static async Task<bool> taskWrapper()
{
    bool firstIn = await signal.WaitAsync(0);

    if (firstIn)
    {
        await baseTask();
        signal.Release();
    }
    else
    {
        await signal.WaitAsync();
        signal.Release();
    }

    return firstIn;
}
```

Then your multiple threads would await `taskWrapper()` rather than awaiting `baseTask()` directly.

Putting that altogether in a compilable console application:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (int it = 0; it < 10; ++it)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\nStarting iteration {it}");
                Task[] tasks = new Task[5];

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                    tasks[i] = Task.Run(demoTask);

                Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nFinished");                  
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static async Task demoTask()
        {
            int id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread {id} starting");

            bool firstIn = await taskWrapper();

            Console.WriteLine($"Task {id}: executed: {firstIn}");
        }

        static async Task<bool> taskWrapper()
        {
            bool firstIn = await signal.WaitAsync(0);

            if (firstIn)
            {
                await baseTask();
                signal.Release();
            }
            else
            {
                await signal.WaitAsync();
                signal.Release();
            }

            return firstIn;
        }

        static async Task baseTask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting long method.");
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished long method.");
        }

        static readonly SemaphoreSlim signal = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    }
}
```

(The methods are all static because they are in a console app; in real code they would be non-static methods.)

Answer (score 2):

`await` doesn't necessarily use continuations (the `Task.ContinueWith` kind) at all. Even when it does, you can have multiple continuations on one `Task` - they just can't all run synchronously (and you might run into some issues if you have a synchronization context).

Do note that your pseudo-code isn't thread-safe, though - you can't just do `currentTask = DoAsyncNetworkIO();` outside of a lock. Only the `await` itself is thread-safe, and even then, only because the `Task` class that you're awaiting implements the `await` contract in a thread-safe way. Anyone can write their own awaiter/awaitable, so make sure to pay attention :)

Comment: *`await` doesn't use continuations (the `Task.ContinueWith` kind) at all* Can you provide reference for this claim? As I can judge from [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com): `TaskAwaiter.OnCompleted` calls `TaskAwaiter.OnCompletedInternal` calls `Task.SetContinuationForAwait` calls `Task.AddTaskContinuation`. While public `Task.ContinueWith` calls private `Task.ContinueWith` calls `Task.ContinueWithCore` calls `Task.AddTaskContinuation`. So both way ends up calling the same method in the end.

Comment: @PetSerAl Right, that was a bit bolder than intended. Let me fix that :)